# Creating terrain

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, physics, car, processing

[I am working on creating a 2D side-scrolling car game](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/car-physics-thingy/5378059343). My problem is generating the terrain. When creating the terrain, I need to have it random and recorded, so I can create collisions at a later point. I can't use any external assets.

```
var keys = [];

var keyPressed = function() {
    keys[keyCode] = true;
};

var keyReleased = function() {
    keys[keyCode] = false;
};

var car = function(locatio, accel, image, dragcoof) {
    this.loc = locatio;
    this.accel = accel;
    this.image = image;
    this.volocity = new PVector(0, 0);
    this.acceleration = new PVector(0, 0);
    this.drag = new PVector(0, 0);
    this.dragcoof = new PVector(dragcoof.x, dragcoof.y);
};

car.prototype.draw = function() {
    if (this.image === null) {
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        rect(this.loc.x, this.loc.y, 50, 10);
    } 
    else {
        this.image(this.loc.x, this.loc.y);
    }
};

car.prototype.update = function() {
    if (this.volocity.x >= 10) {
        this.volocity.x = 9.99;
    }

    if (this.volocity.x <= 0.1) {
        this.volocity.x = 0;
    }

    this.volocity.add(this.acceleration);
    this.loc.add(this.volocity);
    this.drag = PVector.mult(this.volocity, this.dragcoof);
    this.volocity.sub(this.drag);

    if (this.loc.x >= 600) {
        this.loc.x = 0;
    }
};

car.prototype.move = function(keycodeLeft, keycodeRight) {
    if (keys[RIGHT] && this.volocity.x < 10) {
        this.acceleration.add(this.accel.x,0);
    }

    if (!keys[RIGHT] && !keys[LEFT]) {
        this.acceleration.set(0, 0);
    }

    if (keys[LEFT] && this.volocity.x >= 0.5) {
        this.acceleration.set(-0.1, 0);
    }
};

var a = new car(new PVector(10, 200), new PVector(0.01,0), null, new PVector(0.022, 0));

var draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    a.draw();
    a.update();
    a.move();
    text(a.acceleration + "\n" + a.volocity+"\n"+a.drag, 25, 25);
};
```

Comment: You've told us your *problem*.. ***What is your question***?

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that you spelt *velocity* wrong. It doesn't necessarily matter, but if you try to reference it later using the correct spelling, your gunna have a bad time.

Comment: Terrain generation is a huge topic, so you'll need to narrow your question down a bit further for it to fit the StackExchange Q&A format. Consider including mock images of the kind of terrain output you want, and describe the algorithms you've considered/implemented so far, and what specifically you feel needs improvement.

Comment: Your question does not show any effort. What have you tried? Take a look at [what's been asked before](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=terrain+generation+is%3Aquestion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally for generating terrain(either 2D or 3D), you need a base "random" factor, something you can base your terrain of. There are several nice algorithms and tutorials for generating those, and with some arithmetic calculations you can easily customize them for you own needs. Some examples are the [Perlin noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) or the [Simplex noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_noise). Do a bit of research on those, experiment with parameters and you're good to go.